# VB.Net: "Nice", maintainable way of matching integer error code to error strings for UI

Tags: vb.net, string, user-interface

I'm building a user interface (HMI, human-machine interface) for a machine that does various motion-controlled tasks. The motion controller is a bit on the primitive side in terms of programming, and so I have it sending me error and status codes in the form of integers.

As an example: I have a box that indicates what stage the machine is at during its autocycle. The machine sends a '1', and I want the box to say 'Waiting to start autocycle.' Here are a few more:

```
1  - Waiting to start autocycle.
2  - Returning to home.
3  - Waiting at home.
4  - Tracking encoder A.
5  - Tracking encoder B.
```

And so on. Is there a clean way to maintain these messages in VB.net using, say, resources, that I don't know about, or should I just make an XML file that just contains something like

```
<statusmessage code="1" message="Waiting to start autocycle.">
```

and read that in when the program starts?

My current method is a hard-coded select statement with the strings in the actual VB source so you have to recompile the program if you want to change a message (gross).

If it's relevant, this program is never going to be multi-language.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You could have a dictionary or hash table ...How often are these messages going to change?

Comment: It's not that they're going to change that often, it's more like they should be easy to read when a person is going on-site to service the machine and the UI isn't connected to the motion controller. We currently maintain an Excel spreadsheet that (tries) to line up with the select statement. The dictionary makes more sense instead of my select statement... perhaps I can read into a dictionary from an XML file.

Comment: Yes XML to dictionary would suffice with LINQ and or without it...

Comment: I would use a `SortedList(Of Int32, String)` ... along with a text file in application directory and use `Application.ExecutablePath` or `.StartupPath.` to load it.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do this with an .xml file. That or some similar file format would be my preference. Some people would prefer using app.config or file format. When I evaluate something like this, simplicity of maintenance is probably the highest priority, and there are several methods that would work equally well in this regard. A database table could be used, but it seems like an overcomplication.

Comment: As per Mr CoDeXeR's comment above and your answer here, I am working on a fairly straightforward solution that simply looks everything up from an XML "dictionary" using LINQ queries. When I have the time, I'll post it as an answer. Too bad Stack Exchange doesn't have "major contribution" answers, but I will upvote your answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to worry about multiple languages, it is possible to do this...

```
Public Enum Foo
    <Description("Waiting to start autocycle")> WaitingToStartAutoCycle = 1
    <Description("Returning to home")> ReturningToHome = 2
    ' [ etc...]
End Enum
```

You can then use reflection to get the description.  This is ripped out of a larger piece of code, so forgive me if I miss part of it..

```
Public Function GetEnumDescription(ByVal value As Object) As String
    Dim type As Type = value.GetType()
    ' Excersize for the reader, validate that type is actually an Enum
    Dim f As FieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString)
    If f IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim ca() As Object = f.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False)
        If ca IsNot Nothing AndAlso ca.Length > 0 Then
            Return CType(ca(0), DescriptionAttribute).Description
        End If
    End If
    Return value.ToString  ' Last resort if no Description attribute
End Function
```

Comment: This seems more complex than "Select case 0 string = "bob" case 1 string = "joe" etc that I'm using right now, with no real maintainability benefit. The code isn't any more user-readable...

Comment: This has the advantage of keeping the description in the same place as the actual enum, and the function is usable by any enum that you use this technique on.  The `Select Case` method is OK too, but I would hope that you would use actual enum values in the Cases.  "Magic Numbers" are Evil and should be avoided

Comment: Yes, fair enough. It was all located in one place so it's roughly as complex if I were to implement your method, but yours would allow me to make it more complicated without it turning into a nightmare.